# Innovative JavaScript function improvement

Tags: javascript

Often I see interview question/answers for upgrade myself, one of questions was: *how you could write a function to make a deep array flat?*

example:

```
var array = [1,[2],[3,[4,[5,[7,[8]]]]],[6]];
```

The interviewer answer it like down code:

```
var res = array.toString().split(',');
```

But the SO doesn't accept it, why? it works awesome and the interviewer doesn't use `flatten` function of new JavaScript.

Comment: `But the interviewer doesn't accept it, why?` Sounds like a question to ask the interviewer, not SO

Comment: maybe because you change the type of the values.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, you right, I will fix it.

Comment: @NinaScholz, please write for me a true answer, it works well.

Comment: If you would tell the interviewer why this thing works the way it works...especially the toString() part, then you're very good to go. Because, as you will start explaining toString() you will realize this method is called by each child element in a recursive fashion, just like in an actual solution.

Comment: it is clever, and works fine with numbers, but if you start mixing strings in you can get wrong answers, I would highly discourage this type of solutions unless you are using something like typescript, and even then... who knows where it might be used and cause bugs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution provided doesn't work in the following case:

```
var array = ["abc",["def,ghi"]];
var res = array.toString().split(',');
```

You'd get an array of 3 elements instead of 2. The question doesn't make any assumptions over the type of the values.